# Rails Friendly_id: Slug isn't generated properly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, slug, friendly-id

I'm trying to make my custom slug using FriendlyId gem like:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug_candidates, :use => [:slugged, :finders]

def slug_candidates
   id = rand(100..200)
   x = ...
   y = ...
   return "#{x}-#{y}-#{id}"
end
```

Before adding the slug column, when I test it in the `rails console` with `.friendly_id`, is shows the slug correctly in the format of x-y-id. The problem is that when I add a slug column and try making new instances, just the last part is saved (only a random number) as the slug! There's not the values of x and y in the slug. What's wrong here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to do something like this:

```
def slug_candidates
   id = rand(100..200)
   x = ...
   y = ...
  [ "#{x}-#{y}-#{id}" ]
end

def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  true
end
```